# Capture arguments after PIPE in a bash script as string

Tags: linux, shell-script, pipe, arguments

I am writing a simple script (well, I thought it would be simple) to gather and log a 'reason' for using sudo. That part is working pretty straightforward based on another article I found (https://community.unix.com/t/sudo-prompt-for-comment-text/265046/4).

However, the script I have falls apart if the user uses PIPE ( | ) in their command, e.g.

`mysudo.sh cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i something`

With the command above, the script will effectively pause at the pipe, and does nothing until you hit enter/return, then it bypasses the if statement and just "sits there" with a blank cursor. When you hit enter, it will run the sudo command as entered, however nothing is ever logged.

If I use something like:

`./mysudo.sh ls -lh /var/log/syslog`

the if statement is triggered and if the user is in the GROUP group, then it prompts for a reason, logs the event, then runs the sudo and command properly.

What I'd like to do is to capture all the data after 'mysudo.sh' as a string then use that in my script. Does anyone have a way to do this? The end goal is to symlink this new script to sudo so that the end user is unaware of the wrapper, other than to now have to enter a reason if certain criteria are met.  My thought with capturing the arguments (including what is after the pipe) into a string would be to change the two sudo lines (and the reason string) to something like:

`ENTEREDCOMMAND=<the string of arguements, including the pipe and other data> ... sudo ${ENTERETEDCOMMAND}`

(With examples from this question)

`ENTEREDCOMMAND would equal "cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i something" ... sudo ${ENTERETEDCOMMAND}`

Script below:

Any help would be appreciated!

```
logFile=/path/to/log.log
shopt -s nocasematch
clear

GROUP=$(groups | grep -i "GROUP")

if [[ ${GROUP} =~ "GROUP" ]];
then //if user is GROUP capture the reason for sudo, then proceed with sudo
  echo '
  Enter the reason for executing the command with elevated privileges (include a ticket # is possible): '
  read response
  echo "$USER" 'executed "'${*}'" at '"$(date)"' with a reason of "'${response}'".' >> $logFile
  sudo $*
else
  sudo $* //if the user is NOT in the GROUP above, run sudo as normal
fi
```

Comment: Welcome, besides other problems, you have the same command `sudo $*` in both conditions so it is always executed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly means "the script I have falls apart". You should create a minimal reproducible example by removing all lines that are not necessary to reproduce the problem, for example the `GROUP` stuff and the corresponding `if`. When you run `mysudo.sh cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i something`, your script will actually be run as `mysudo.sh cat /var/log/syslog` and its output will be passed to `grep -i something` using a pipe. So the output of the first `echo` command will be sent to `grep` and you will not see it.

Comment: The script may also break the behavior of the command specified by the user because `read response` might consume input that is intended for the command. Example `sudo tee /path/to/dest_file < source_file`

Comment: Using `$*` will break on anything that contains spaces or quoted values. You should use `sudo "$@"` and for the `echo` statement use `echo "$USER executed '$*' at $(date) with a reason of '$response}'." >> "$logFile"`. All your variables should be inside double quotes

Comment: Why not force the user to enclose the command in single quotes?

Comment: @Bodo - edited the question to be more concise. Thank you in advance!

Noted on the "$@" vs "$*" I will work that in after I fix the PIPE issue.

I would rather NOT force the user to change their behavior (other than to have to log a reason, for auditing purposes). And, if I make it so they have to enclose their commands in single quotes, how do I prevent them from bypassing that?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity - That is by design - the goal is to ignore the audit logging I am building unless the user is in certain groups. I guess I should add an escape/end in the first part of the if. Good catch. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielHayes you can for example check that only one argument is passed.

Comment: @bodo - the read response (as far as I can tell) works fine - it only captures the reason that is entered.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity - I am not understanding your request. Check that only one argument is passed? Do you mean inform the user they can't PIPE to other commands? I can, but that hamstrings the users, so would be a detriment. I'd prefer to make the replacement sudo/sudo wrapper as transparent as possible.

Comment: @GabrielHayes I mean, if you enclose the argument in single quotes, only one argument, a string, will be passed: `script.sh 'echo foo | grep foo'`. In `script.sh`: `echo "$1" → echo foo | grep foo`. Then you can `bash -c "$1"`.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in the shell, but I do in C/C++! You could write a small C or C++ program that takes a command as argument `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, concatenates the strings to reassemble your command, asks the user for a reason with printf/scanf (C) or cout/cin (C++), logs the input to a file (`fopen("/var/log/sudo.log", "a");` or the C++ equivalent in fstream, then proceeding using normal file IO techniques), and then passes on the command directly to the shell using a SYSTEM() call. Maybe a square peg in a round hole (or overkill), but it would work - and it'd be fast :P

Comment: There might be some misunderstanding. Whan you enter `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i something`, only `cat /var/log/syslog` will be run as `root`. The pipe will be created by your shell *before* starting `sudo`, and the `grep` command will be run as the normal user. For a security audit it is not relevant if the output of a command run as `root` is processed by a pipe. The same happens with your script `mysudo`. It will not get the pipe as a command line argument unless you quote it, but then it would be more difficult to make your script behave similar to `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughts and input. After many attempts, I went a different route - I am taking my script and just stripping all arguments, then logging the reason (if necessary), then prompting for the command to run, storing that as a string, then using eval to run that command. Works like a charm.

Thank you however! I truly appreciate it and learned a lot!

Comment: You realise that if your script boils down to `sudo "$@"` then there's still nothing technically significant stopping people just accessing `sudo` directly?

Comment: @roaima, yes I do. I worked around that by renaming my script to sudo, plopping it into a tools directory and the putting that directory at the beginning of the path variable in environment and restricting access to the absolute path of sudo. It works, but it's not perfect. The idea isn't to harden the system, but to keep the honest more honest for our auditing team.

Comment: That's only "security by obscurity". If you want to lock it down properly, rewrite your script to automatically call _itself_ with `sudo`, vet its arguments, and then call the desired code (without another `sudo` since you're already running as root). Change the `sudoers` configuration to allow only your script. But after all this, it's worth mentioning that `sudo` already logs the information you want - just in a slightly different format